# PHP how to pass URL parameters to create a new URL

Tags: php, url

Very newbie question: setting up a Meraki wireless EXCAP walled garden, and will have users land on a terms-of-service.php (simple checkbox)... upon submission, will land on page with other info THEN need to pass to open web. Need to grab first URL, save it, pass to page2.php, and then out to web.

Meraki's example of incoming URL (when user attempts to access wireless):

```
http://MyCompany.com/MerakiSplashPage/?base_grant_url=https://example.meraki.com/splash/grant&user_continue_url=http://www.google.com&node_id=222222&gateway_id=222222&client_ip=10.222.222.222
```

Then "When you are ready to grant access to the user, send the user to `GET['base_grant_url'] + "?continue_url=" + GET['user_continue_url']`. In the case of the example above, this URL would be:

```
https://example.meraki.com/splash/grant?continue_url=http://www.google.com
```

Going in circles on how to do this, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what page or pages are you writing?  Maybe if you could be a little more clear on the series of pages the user will go through and what pages you need help with.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) to encode the value properly:

```
'http://MyCompany.com/MerakiSplashPage/?base_grant_url='.rawurlencode('https://example.meraki.com/splash/grant&user_continue_url=http://www.google.com').'&node_id=222222&gateway_id=222222&client_ip=10.222.222.222'
```

You can also use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) to build the query automatically:

```
$query = array(
    'base_grant_url' => 'https://example.meraki.com/splash/grant&user_continue_url=http://www.google.com',
    'node_id' => '222222',
    'gateway_id' => '222222',
    'client_ip' => '10.222.222.222'
);
'http://MyCompany.com/MerakiSplashPage/?'.http_build_query($query)
```

Comment: Thanks Gumbo & Babiker, I was going in the wrong direction, by trying to use parse_url and wasn't getting anywhere. Will try these... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your final URL would be:

```
$_GET['base_grant_url']."?".$_GET['user_continue_url'];
```